# Windows 10 serial and BIOS with multiple partitions

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios

I have two partitions on my PC. One is Windows 10 Pro and one is Windows 10 Home.

I want to wipe the drive completely and have one clean Windows 10 Pro partition. The serial number that is been written to BIOS is the Windows Home key. I'm concerned that when I do a clean install it will use the home serial number rather than the pro.

How can I ensure the Pro serial us used? Can I force an override in BIOS or is there a way when installing Windows 10 that I can specify the serial number to use.

I have used this command to extract the serial stored in bios:

```
(Get-WmiObject -query 'select * from SoftwareLicensingService').OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

And I've ran Belarc Advisor in the Pro partition and the two keys do not match.

Thanks.

Comment: “How can I ensure the Pro serial us used?” - Modify the ISO to include the appropriate names text file containing the Professional license key, or simply install Home, then upgrade it to Professional after the fact.

Comment: I'm with Ramhound. Yes the second Windows may activate itself using the Home key in the BIOS but that's not really a problem, you can simply upgrade the key in Windows and have done with or enter the correct key during installation.

Comment: EI.cfg is the real solution. Otherwise, the edition will be automatically detected.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, that worked a treat.